# Duplicate events when using firestore hooks in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am building a react chat app using react/firebase.

I am trying to add presence functionality for users by creating documents containing online users details.

Using firestore hooks to detect when a user logs in ends by adding him twice even if I check if he already exists.

```
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
  const [soundState, setSoundState] = useState(false);
  const onlineRef = firestore.collection('onlineUsers');
  const soundToggle = (e) => {
    setSoundState(e.target.checked)
  }

  if (user){
//if I console.log(user) it logs the user info twice
    const query = onlineRef.where("userId","==",user.uid)
    query.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      if(querySnapshot.empty){
        onlineRef.add({
          userId: user.uid,
          Name: user.displayName,
          Photo: user.photoURL,
          lastLogIn: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })
      }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
  }
```

btw I am new to react hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except it seems that your code starting with `if(user){...` is on the render path, so it is executed every time your component renders. You should instead execute this code in a `useEffect` hook, as such:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            const query = onlineRef.where("userId", "==", user.uid);
            query
                .get()
                .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                        onlineRef.add({
                            userId: user.uid,
                            Name: user.displayName,
                            Photo: user.photoURL,
                            lastLogIn: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                });
        }
        // Optionally: return a function that removes the user from onlineUsers
    }, [user]);
```

We set the `user` variable as a dependency, so the content of useEffect will run every time this variable content changes.
Additionally, you could return a function to clean up the onlineUsers collection when the component unmounts. [cf useEffect with clean-up doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)